# Debian 6 internet problem: ifconfig doesn't show eth0

Tags: debian, networking, internet

I just installed 64-bit Debian 6.06 on my ASUS K53S machine and internet is not working... Wireless is working fine.

NetworkManager is doesn't show any wired connections and ifconfig in the terminal doesn't show any eth0 interface My `/etc/network/interfaces` file has the following lines

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Googling for it didn't help. Any help anyone?

Comment: What model of network card it has?

Comment: Does ifconfig -a show the interface? (ifconfig doesn't show interfaces that aren't up nowadays, but ifconfig -a does)

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Linux on an ASUS laptop as well and the ethernet card is an Atheros ethernet+bluetooth combo whose driver hasn't been integrated in the vanilla kernel yet.

Check the hardware ID of your ethernet card (`lspci -nn`) and see if [this](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx) applies to you.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding this to `/etc/network/interfaces`?

for DHCP:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

or for static:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

I suppose your network card is working and driver is properly loaded, check it with `lspci` or simply with `grep eth0 /proc/net/dev`.

Comment: `lspci` will show whether the hardware is detected at all; try `awk -e '{print $1}' < /proc/net/dev` to see whether Linux is able to use the interface. (Plain `grep` or `cat` work too, obviously, but display a little more than you might care for...)